# Problemas con Live Server en VScode

Tags: html, css

Tengo problemas con Live Server en Vscode, cuando intento hacer la carga del sitio web a traves de Go Live no me abre la ventana del navegador por ningun metodo. Muestro la captura de pantalla de configuracion del archivo .json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Necesitas *settings* adicionales referentes al *https* o algún *proxy*?

Comment: No.  Es para trabajar localmente. Creo que tuve problemas con Xampp,

Comment: con los siguientes valores no funciona tampoco   
                                                  
"php.executablePath":"C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",

Comment: Yo diría que te sobran todas las configuraciones. Sólo necesitas `"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"` exactamente como lo tienes y `"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": ""`. Todas las referentes a `php` y de `liveServer` bórralas.

Comment: hice lo que mencionaste y nada

Comment: la cosa sigue igual...no abre en el navegador

Comment: quedo asi:                                                                                
      "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    
     "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "",
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"

Comment: Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder.

Comment: Deberías agregar el código como texto no como imagen.

Comment: @Bicho lo gregue asi para que lo observaran mejor

Answer (score 0):

Estimado tienes que borrar todo sobre liveServer y poner esto

```
{
"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
"liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": verdadero,
"liveServer.settings.port": 0,
"liveServer.settings.multiRootWorkspaceName": "",
"liveServer.settings.fullReload ": verdadero,
"liveServer.settings.useLocalIp ": verdadero
}
```

Suerte!

Comment: y eso como por qué?

Comment: Agrega un poco de explicacion del porque debe hacer eso.